# Using Bubble sort and encountering out of range list index

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

```
doc = "unsorted.txt"
out_fil = "H:\Grade 11\Intro to Computer Science\sorted.txt" # Used in the Windows variation of the program
out_file = "/Applications/Banter" # Used in the Mac variation of the program
import time
def main():
    order = False
    blank = []
    passcount = 0
    starttime = time.time()
    numlist = CreateList(doc)
    while not order:
        passcount = passcount + 1
        switch = False
        switchcount = 0
        print "1" # These are test prints to I used to find problems
        for x in range (len(numlist)):
            print "2" # These are test prints to I used to find problems
            if numlist[x] > numlist[x+1]:
                temp = numlist[x+1]
                numlist[x+1] = numlist[x]
                numlist[x] = temp
                switchcount = switchcount + 1
                switch = True
                print "9" # These are test prints to I used to find problems
            elif switch == 0:
                order = True


    CreateFile(numlist)
    endtime = time.time()
    print "This list required",endtime-starttime,"seconds to sort."
    print "This list required",switchcount,"switches to sort."
    print "This list required",passcount,"passes to sort."



def CreateList(doc):
    sort = open(doc,"r")
    numlist = sort.readlines()
    sort.close()
    for x in range (len(numlist)):
        numlist[x] = int(numlist[x].strip())
    return numlist

def CreateFile(numlist):
    sort = open(doc,"w")
    sort.write(str(numlist)+"\n")
    sort.close()
    return numlist

def List(numlist):
    print numlist

main()
```

The main purpose of my program is to sort a list of integers from a file in order using the bubble sort method, and then put that list into a new file. I'm also detailing the amount of time it takes to perform this as well as the number of passes and switches within the program that it took to sort it completely.

Now, the problem I'm having is that the list index falls out of range because it's comparing x and x+1 of my numlist. But, I need to compare x+1 in order to sort the two integers beside each others within the list. Is there any way I can fix the program so that it'll compare all the integers in the list and not try to compare the space that isn't in the list because of the x+1?

Comment: FYI, you can streamline the three lines of `temp = numlist[x+1];numlist[x+1] = numlist[x];numlist[x] = temp` to `numlist[x], numlist[x+1] = numlist[x+1], numlist[x]`.  It's a nice one-liner that dispenses with the need to explicitly create a temp variable.  (A temporary tuple is created behind the scenes for the right side and then unpacked and assigned to the left side.  Google python tuple unpacking for more.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your loop in this way:

```
for x in range ( len(numlist) -1 ):
```

Answer (score 0):

Though stackoverflow is a great resource for answers, giving them up for homework assignments feels like cheating. I'll meet you half way: Make your loop run for one less iteration.